# systemd - Is this how to require a service by an installed program?

Tags: systemd, symlink, systemd-unit

**The essence:**
I want the systemd to symlink specific directories to `/tmp/some_folder` before it starts services from various installed packages and system services *(like cups, pacman, etc.)*, the reason: I don't want them writing logs on my disk, or, in other words, I want to make my system as read-only as possible. I want to ask here if my planned solution it is indeed a solution.

**The details:**
My distro is ArchLinux and here is what I imagine a solution would be:
Let `L` be the list of services that I want to require my symlinks:
(`cups.socket`, `pacman-filesdb-refresh.service`, `systemd-logind.service`, `systemd-timesyncd.service`, `NetworkManager.service`)
I create a custom service `y` with these properties:
`Requires= -.mount tmp.mount` (to be able to find `/bin/bash` and have `/tmp` mounted)
`After=    -.mount tmp.mount`
`Before=   L`
which runs a bash script to create the symlinks (I added spaces for readability).
Then, I create folders `x.requires` for each `x` from `L`, and in each of them I make a symlink to `y.service`.

**The questions:**
My questions are:

1. Does this resemble a possible solution?
2. What kind of service should `y` be in order to appear as active only when the bash script finishes and succeeds?
3. Where do these `x.requires` directories need to be placed? Can I just put them in the same directory somewhere among locations from `systemd-analyze unit-paths`?

Comment: Why do you want to manually make the Requires symlinks? Just have your service have `RequiredBy` directive listing the affected services.

Comment: @muru Okay, you are right, I must have missed that potential in my short crash course about systemd. Could you please give me your opinion on validity of this solution, assuming I implement your suggestion? EDIT: I probably was thinking in the direction of creating a static service, one that can't be disabled because it shouldn't ever, but given that I will be the only one in control I should care more about practicality and thus accept your suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, I would probably just mount tmpfs on these problematic directories directly.

Comment: @muru By directly, you mean what exactly? I am not sure. EDIT: I understand now, sorry, you meant to mount them as separate tmpfs drives. In that case I would just have to change the contents of the service `y`, but the order of execution and dependencies are still the same. These problematic services won't wait for all the tmpfs drives to mount, they only wait for `-.mount` and they start logging immediately. That's why I (think I) need these dirty means.

Comment: I mean either use systemd mount units or `fstab` entries to mount `tmpfs` on these directories. Then there's no need to make symlinks every boot. At most you might to make an override on the services that adds `Requires`/`After` relations to the mount units.

Comment: Also for creating links like these, `systemd-tmpfiles` is an option: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/tmpfiles.d.html

Comment: @muru That was exactly my initial idea, but it has its flaws. I knew how possible it is and what the flaws were and that's exactly why I thought of this new idea and that's why I came here to ask for more opinions. The flaw is that, as you said, I would have to override the problematic services. It is undesirable because I would have to do it after each update of their packages, which adds more scripts and more updates to the disk, countering my goal of making a read-only system. The main thing you can help me now is - shy should I reconsider my old idea over this new one?

Comment: Uh, there's no need to keep overriding services after each package update. Creating override files in `/etc/systemd/system` (like `systemctl edit` does) is persistent. Just don't edit the file in `/usr/lib/systemd` directly. https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/158442

Comment: @muru Now that's something new! Thank you for this, I will seriously reconsider my options now. Now for the sakes of completeness and my own curiosity, can you spot any potential flaws of my idea described in the question, please? I probably can dig out answer to my second and third question on my own, on the inernet, but I am too unaware of some more subtle ways this whole thing could break. I would consider my question answered (closed) after that.

Comment: Instead of all this, you could just write `WantedBy=basic.target` in your `[Install]` section of your unit file. Should that target be too high, you might use lower targets, or self define a target. You should read more about systemd targets. ;-)

Comment: @muru gave a good way to totally override vendor settings, but consider overriding only some settings via a drop-in.  See [systemd.unit examples](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Examples), specifically example 2 (overriding vendor settings).   To make this even easier, use `systemctl edit <service>` and it'll manage your drop-ins for you.